# What does heuristics in Overcommit_memory =0 mean?

Tags: kernel, memory, out-of-memory

I read through the docs of man proc. When it comes to the overcommit_memory, the heuristics in overcommit_memory=0 isn't understood well. What the heuristics actually mean?

does "calls of mmap(2) with MAP_NORESERVE are not checked" mean that the Kernel only allocate virtual memory without being aware of even the existence of swap space?

```
 This file contains the kernel virtual memory accounting mode.  Values are:

                     0: heuristic overcommit (this is the default)
                     1: always overcommit, never check
                     2: always check, never overcommit

              In mode 0, calls of mmap(2) with MAP_NORESERVE are not checked, and the default check is very weak, leading to the  risk
              of getting a process "OOM-killed".
```

Apart from preceding questions, will exhaustion of the virtual address space cause the OOM regardless of the enough remaining physical memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `overcommit_memory` setting is taken into account in three places in the memory-management subsystem.

1. The main one is [`__vm_enough_memory`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/util.c#n582) in `mm/util.c`, which decides whether enough memory is available to allow a memory allocation to proceed (note that this is a utility function which isn’t necessarily invoked). If `overcommit_memory` is 1, this function always succeeds. If it’s 2, it checks the actual available memory. If it’s 0, it uses the famous heuristic which you mention; that proceeds as follows:

   - count the number of free pages
   - add the number of file-backed pages (these can be recovered)
   - remove pages used for shared memory
   - add swap pages
   - add reclaimable pages
   - account for reserved pages
   - leave some memory for root (if the allocation isn’t being done by a `cap_sys_admin` process)

   The resulting total is used as the threshold for memory allocations.
2. [`mmap`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/mmap.c) also checks the setting: `MAP_NORESERVE` is honoured if overcommit is allowed (modes 0 and 1), and results in allocations with no backing swap (`VM_NORESERVE`). In this particular case, mode 0 is effectively equivalent to mode 1; this is what “calls of `mmap(2)` with `MAP_NORESERVE` are not checked” is referring to: it means that `MAP_NORESERVE` `mmap` calls will always succeed, and over-allocation will result in the OOM-killer stepping in after the fact, or a segment violation when a write is attempted.
3. [`shmem`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/shmem.c) has similar behaviour to `mmap`.

Running out of address space should cause allocation failures, not OOM-kills, since the allocation can’t actually proceed.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Regarding the last question. Actually I mean virtual memory by address space. Will running out of virtual memory result in OOM-kills？

Comment: What do you mean by virtual memory here? Physical + swap?